# Assign Values to .Net Property Array with Index Implied

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is it possible to (or how can I) assign values to a class property array like this:

```
MyImgClass.RGB = (255,255,255)
```

I'm not sure how to build my Public Property setter to allow this, if it's possible at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have the following property:

```
Public Class MyImgClass

    Public Property RGB As Integer()

End Class
```

Then you can do:

```
myImgClassInstance.RGB = {255,255,255}
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for. Probably a dumb question but how do I reference each value in the property array separately inside my class object?

Comment: By array index: myImgClassInstance.RGB(0) for red, .RGB(1) for green, .RGB(2) for blue.

Comment: This code: myImgClassInstance.RGB = {255,255,255} causes an error in my error list. It says "Expression expected" and the first curly brace is underlined. I'm not seeing any errors in my class. I am using a custom interface (for COM interop purposes) and all of my properties are declared private and set via the Property Set statements.

Comment: I tested the code and it does work, with VB10 at least. You can also try: x.RGB = New Integer() {255,255,255}

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I had to change it to the statement you listed in order to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper method which accepts parameters and builds your object, something like [Color.FromArgb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557.aspx). If you do not have source code for the class you can implement it as an extension method.

Answer (score 0):

You would make a 'property bucket' object with those values and assign that to the property.

So, in C# (my apologies, but it should be easy enough to convert to vb)

```
public MyRGBClass RGB { get; set; }
```

And then:

```
MyImgClass.RGB = new MyRGBClass(255, 255, 255);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make RGB an object with 3 properties, red, green, and blue?